# Microsoft.SqlServer.Types failed to load

Tags: c#, entity-framework, first-chance-exception

When I have `first-chance exceptions` enabled in `VS2010`, I get the following message the first time I call `EntityFramework's` `SaveChanges()`. This is a `WinForms` application running a `MSSQL CE 4` database.

> **BindingFailure** The assembly with display name 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types' failed to
>   load in the 'Load' binding context of the AppDomain with ID 1. The
>   cause of the failure was: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its
>   dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not
>   match the assembly reference.

After continuing, this message is also displayed:

> **FileLoadException**
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Types,
>   Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80131040)

I've included the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll` in the project.

I know this is a first-chance exception and it doesn't seem to affect the application outside of the notice when I debug, but I'd like to fix it anyways. (It's bugging me in the back of my mind.)

First, what is this error message trying to tell me?

Second, how do I fix it?

Comment: You need to install the Windows.SqlServer.Types package...
Download from http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=16978 or install the nugGet pack using `Install-Package Microsoft.SqlServer.Types`

Comment: @noobob I'm not seeing the Windows.SqlServer.Types package. Am I missing it or is it called something else? Downloading the "package" at the top gets me a txt file that says `The links to the SQL Server 2008 R2 Feature Pack components can be found in the “Instructions” section on the SQL Server 2008 R2 Feature Pack page.` However, I don't see a download in the instructions section for said package.

Comment: @noobob I've installed the package and still receive the message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using spatial types EF needs to probe what SqlTypes are loaded in the AppDomain to bind to it to use it when talking to the SqlServer. [Here](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/SqlTypesAssemblyLoader.cs) is the code that does it. If you look at the `BindToLatest()` method you will see that the exception if actually being caught and ignored. You only see it when you debug since you probably have the "break when an exception is thrown" option checked (Debug -> Exceptions, Common Language Runtime Exceptions, "Thrown" column)

Answer (score 0):

A first-chance exception is not a problem to fix. If the exception is handled, then there will be no impact on your code.

It's unhandled exceptions that you need to worry about.